# Simulating new[] with argument constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, new-operator

If I am not modifying any `static` variable inside the argument constructor, is below the proper way to simulate `new T[N] (x,y);` (array new with arguments) ?

```
template<typename T>
void* operator new [] (size_t size, const T &value)
{
  T* p = (T*) malloc(size);
  for(int i = size / sizeof(T) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    memcpy(p + i, &value, sizeof(T));
  return p;
}
```

Usage will be,

```
struct A
{
  A () {}  // default
  A (int i, int j) {} // with arguments
};

int main ()
{
  A *p = new(A(1,2)) A[10];  // instead of new A[10](1,2)
}
```

Comment: You could avoid some copying by passin `const T& value` instead of `T value`

Comment: `T value ... memcpy(..., &value, ...);` is certainly *not* a good idea.

Comment: I think the approach is **plain wrong**. Any variant of new is ***not*** supposed to construct anything. It only returns an address for the constructor to be called at. Also you would need to provide a matching `operator delete` in case the construction fails. But no, don't do this. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: If this was working, why isn't it in the language already?

Comment: @Alextandre, thanks for pointing it out. I missed to put a debug in default constructor :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *isn’t* OK. You are copying objects into uninitialised memory without invoking proper copy semantics.

*As long as* you’re only working with PODs, this is fine. However, when working with objects that are not PODs (such as your `A`) you need to take precautions.

Apart from that, `operator new` cannot be used in this way. As [Alexandre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373025/alexandre-c) has pointed out in the comments, the array won’t be initialised properly since C++ will call constructors for all elements after having called your `operator new`, thus overriding the values:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void* operator new [] (size_t size, T value) {
    T* p = (T*) std::malloc(size);
    for(int i = size / sizeof(T) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        new(p + i) T(value);
    return p;
}

struct A {
    int x;
    A(int x) : x(x) { std::cout << "int ctor\n"; }
    A() : x(0) { std::cout << "default ctor\n"; }
    A(const A& other) : x(other.x) { std::cout << "copy ctor\n"; }
};

int main() {
    A *p = new(A(42)) A[2];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        std::cout << p[i].x << std::endl;
}
```

This yields:

```
int ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
default ctor
default ctor
0
0
```

… not the desired outcome.

Comment: +1 for the `placement-new`. That is a *huge* improvement over `memcpy`.

Comment: No, don't construct anything into `operator new`. It should only return an address, period.

Comment: @AlexandreC. Not in this overload. The question was *explicitly* after constructing objects, *which is totally fine*. You’re thinking the one-parameter `::operator new`, which is a whole different matter.

Comment: @Konrad: neither placement new nor nothrow new construct anything in their definition either. They only return the address the object should be constructed at. If you do this (which I doubt is possible, since your objects will be overwritten with default constructed objects, potentially leaking a lot of things), then you would also have to provide a matching `operator delete`, in case your `operator new` throws an exception.

Comment: @AlexandreC. Yes but they are different. This overload is a completely different function which just happens to have the same name. This *also* constructs objects. C++ has no restriction that says that an overloaded `operator new` cannot construct objects, in fact quite the opposite – C++ already defines overloads that construct objects: consider for example `new int[10] ()`. This creates a C-array of 10 objects of type `T` *and initialises them*.

Comment: @AlexandreC. But I agree that OP should create a matching `operator delete`.

Comment: @AlexandreC. I concede defeat. Please see my edit, where I have incorporated your correction.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest

```
 std::vector<A> v(10, A(1,2));
```

I realize that this doesn't really address the question for arrays.
You could use

```
 p = &v[0];
```

since the standard guarantees contiguous storage. Be very careful with resizing the vector though, because it could invalidate p

I checked boost::array<> (which adapts C style arrays), but it doesn't define constructors...

Answer (score 2):

That's not okay - C++ will call those objects non-trivial default constructors if `typename T` has such (`struct A` in your example does have one) and that would lead to reconstructing objects in memory already occupied.

An appropriate solution would be to use `std::vector` (recommended) or call `::operator new[]` to allocate memory, then call constructors using placement-new and taking care of exceptions if any.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider that `operator new[]` may be called asking for more memory than the bare amount `sizeof(T) * n`.

This extra memory is possibly needed because C++ must know how many object to destroy in case of `delete[] p;` but it cannot reliably use the size of block of memory allocated by `new p[sz]` to infer this number because the memory may have been asked to a custom memory manager so (e.g. your case) there is no way to know how much memory was allocated only by knowing the pointer.

This also means that your attempt to provide already-initialized objects will fail because the actually array returned to the application will potentially not start at the address you returned from your custom `operator new[]` so that initialization could be misaligned.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename myType> myType * buildArray(size_t numElements,const myType & startValue) {
  myType * newArray=(myType *)malloc(sizeof(myType)*numElements);

  if (NULL!=newArray) {
    size_t index;
    for (index=0;index<numElements;++index) {
      new (newArray+index) myType(startValue);
    }
  }

  return newArray;
}

template <typename myType> void destroyArray(size_t numElements,myType * oldArray) {
  size_t index;
  for (index=0;index<numElements;++index) {
    (oldArray+index)->~myType();
  }
  free(oldArray);
}

A * p=newArray(10,A(1,2));
destroyArray(10,p);
```

destroyArray could also be written like this depending on the platform you are building for:

```
template <typename myType> void destroyArray(myType * oldArray) {
  size_t numElements=malloc_size(oldArray)/sizeof(myType); //or _msize with Visual Studio
  size_t index;
  for (index=0;index<numElements;++index) {
    (oldArray+index)->~myType();
  }
  free(oldArray);
}
```

Comment: Please tell me how in the earth this code has any advantage over `std::vector` ?

Comment: @Alexandre Either from habit or necessity, some people are control freaks when it comes to memory allocation.  I used malloc here but it could it be any other memory allocator.

Comment: @Alexandre These functions provide new[]-like semantics while providing control over object construction which is what the OP asked about.  Not all array questions are XY problems to be answered with STL.